# Laravel 5.4 log 404 in dedicated log file

Tags: laravel, laravel-5, logging

Wish to log 404 errors to dedicated log file, auto cleaned after X days as the standard log files

is this possible?

My laravel version is 5.4

Answer (score 0):

I found this partial solution, in `app\Exceptions\Handler` :

```
...
public function report(Exception $exception){
    if ($exception instanceof \Symfony\Component\HttpKernel\Exception\NotFoundHttpException) {
//THIS LINE ADDS A LOG FILE
        Log::useDailyFiles(storage_path('/logs/404.log',7));
        Log::error('Page not found: ' ...); //log my useful details 
    }elseif($exception instanceof AuthenticationException||$exception instanceof ValidationException){
            //Ignored cases
            return;
        }else{
            //default case
            Log::error('blah blah...');
        }
    }
    ...
    //go on with normal handling
    parent::report($exception);
}
...
```

partial, because the log goes both on the previous file AND to the new file, not exclusively to the added one